# Haskell zip lists with type Int

Tags: haskell

I'm having the following issue in Haskell.

I try to zip a list and numbers in order to number the list
i.e. `zip [1..] mylist`.

However, the type for this is `[(Integer, [String])]`.

Is there any way to get `Int` instead of `Integer` in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal `1` is overloaded, i.e.

```
1 :: Num a => a
```

and will either be `Integer` or `Int`, depending on the context. So if you use `zip [1..] mylist` in a context that expects a type `[(Int, [String])]`, then this will work.

You can also be explicit, by writing `zip [1::Int..] mylist` instead.